# How to Add PK As Foreign Key To Existing Table?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I have created two tables in phpMyAdmin 3.5.8.1. comments which stores comments users post on a website and registration which stores a users registration details (username, password, e-mail etc, etc).

I want to add the username field from the registration table as a foreign key to the comments table.

Comment: Example on [*MySQL: ForeignKey*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#idm47663349396736)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE comments
(
tab_c comments VARCHAR2,
tab_user username VARCHAR2,
PRIMARY KEY (tab_user),
FOREIGN KEY (tab_user) REFERENCES username(tab_registration)
)
```

Comment: Both tables already exist. I tired :  
  
tab_c comments VARCHAR2,  
tab_user username VARCHAR2,  
PRIMARY KEY (tab_user),  
FOREIGN KEY (tab_user) REFERENCES username(tab_registration)  
  
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tab_c comments VARCHAR2, tab_user username VARCHAR2, PRIMARY KEY (tab_user), ' at line 1